# Django Jenkins Test runner - Slow

Tags: python, django, jenkins

I am using django_discover_jenkins module for generating jenkins reports as a part of unit test runs.

Has anyone used this before and found it to be slower? The coverage tasks slow this down considerably.

How do I remove coverage task from the django_discover_jenkins task set without editing the settings file.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude the coverage task, define `TEST_TASKS` in your project's `settings.py`, and leave out the coverage task.

```
TEST_TASKS = (
    # 'discover_jenkins.tasks.run_pylint.PyLintTask',
    'discover_jenkins.tasks.with_coverage.CoverageTask',
)
```

I'm not sure why you don't want to edit settings.py, that's the [documented](https://django-discover-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html) way to do it.

Comment: Am trying not to add unnecessary modules to python for dev environment..this should strictly be for automation. I could edit this file on the fly but was trying to see if there is an easier way. 

However I do find it strange that certain tests run at the same speed as it would with the normal django_discover runner but some specific ones seem to take way too long on this jenkins module compared to the default runner.

Comment: You could use a different settings module when running jenkins, by using the [`--settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings) option.

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest version of original django-jenkins library. It has same unit test discovery method and coverage disabled by default. Coverage could be enabled with `--enable-coverage` command line option.